# ng-click on <a> tag not working in android phonegap

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I am creating phonegap application for android using angular.js.

ng-click on `<a>` tag is not working in phonegap app while it is working in android chrome browser. 
below is the html.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="loadNativePage()">Sign up here!</a>
```

kindly suggest something.

Comment: maybe change href to '#' or change <a> to <button>

Comment: Thanks!, I have tried href and changing it to button would lead changes in CSS so don't wanna go that way.

Comment: so maybe try removing 'href' leave only <a ng-click="... or leave <a href ng-click="..  - href with no arguments